# Check for divisibility by a three digit number in F#

Tags: f#

I want a function isDiv to return true if a number x is divisible by some number i between 100 and 999, and x/i is between 100 and 999; I attempted to write the method below;

```
let isDiv x =
    for i in 101..999 do
        if x%i == 0 && x/i > 100 && x/i < 999 
            0
```

the F# Interactive panel tells me that this is incomplete - Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `if` has no corresponding `then` and equality comparison is `=` not `==`.

But if you use a for-loop you will have to use somewhere a mutable, you can use a while-loop but I would use instead `Seq.exists`:

```
let isDiv x = Seq.exists (fun i -> x%i = 0 && x/i > 100 && x/i < 999) {101..999}
```

Comment: How would I implement the additional condition that x/i be between 100 and 999?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out ; `let isDiv x = Seq.exists (fun i -> x%i = 0 && x/i > 100 && x/i < 999 ) [101..999] `

Comment: @user3677952 be careful with `>` versus `>=` and integer division (for example `3001/30 = 100 ` in integer arithmetic and such a pair would fail the test (ignoring the divisibility test here).